# transpose columns to rows in a spreadsheet

Tags: text-processing, scripting

I have a spreadsheet has one column as the following:

```
            column A    
1                  a
2                  b
3                  c
4                  d
5                  e
```

I want to save this spreadsheet and transpose the column by row as the following:

```
ID   column A column B column C column D column E
1           a        b        c        d        e
```

How can I do that?

Comment: just a note: in the spreadsheet itself, you can also : copy, then "paste as:" transposed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that you’re not telling us all your requirements. 
Based on what you are saying (asking), either of the following should work:

1. `echo $(cat existing_file) > newfile`

   `$(…)` puts the output of the command inside the parentheses on the command line, where the shell converts newlines into spaces.
2. `{ tr '\n' ' ' < existing_file; echo;} > newfile`

   The `tr` converts *every* newline in the existing file (including the very last one) to a space; then add a newline.